# In a MySQL environment that is not strict, is there a way to test a query using strict?

Tags: mysql

I know that there is STRICT_ALL_TABLES, but I am not the admin and absolutely cannot set that on the database. However, I was wondering if I could set that for a query, kind of like select SQL_NO_CACHE, for debugging purposes.

version is 5.1.42

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set strict mode just for your connection with

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

Having set it, you can then execute your query on the same connection.

[See manual for more details.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html)

Comment: I prefer to just use `TRADITIONAL`.

Comment: @Hammerite, don't it uses all kinds of shortcuts that can bite you in many nasty ways.

Comment: @Johan, could you give more details?